# Calculating Holding time

Tags: pandas, time-series

I am new to time-series programming with python.
Consider a file which contains orders for buying or selling stocks and its corresponding status.
The order file contains multiple lines, each line contains the state of the order.

```
Following is sample content of the order file:
{"DATETIME":"20171116 03:46:16.142514", "DATA":
{"MODE":"ORD","INSTR":"INSTR1","TYPE":"New","id":1}}
{"DATETIME":"20171116 03:46:16.243121", "DATA":
{"MODE":"ORD","INSTR":"INSTR2","TYPE":"New","id":2}}
{"DATETIME":"20171116 03:46:16.758292", "DATA":
{"MODE":"ORD","INSTR":"INSTR3","TYPE":"New","id":3}}
{"DATETIME":"20171116 03:46:17.212341", "DATA":
{"MODE":"ORD","INSTR":"INSTR2","TYPE":"TRD","id":2}}
{"DATETIME":"20171116 03:46:17.467893", "DATA":
{"MODE":"ORD","INSTR":"INSTR1","TYPE":"CXL","id":1}}
{"DATETIME":"20171116 03:46:18.924825", "DATA":
{"MODE":"ORD","INSTR":"INSTR3","TYPE":"TRD","id":3}}
```

Details of each fields in a line are as follows
    ● DateTime
    ○ Timestamp of the order

```
○ Format
■ YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss.mi

● MODE
○ Type of the message
○ Always will be ORD
● INSTR
○ Name of the instrument
● TYPE
○ Type of the order
○ Following are the possible values
■ NEW
● Opens a new order
● Order will be active as long as it is in NEW state
■ CXL
● Order got cancelled. Order will be in a closed state after CXL
■ TRD
● Order got traded. Order will be in a closed state after TRD
● ID
○ Unique Id for identifying a particular order
○ Use ID to find state of the same order

We define holding time as the time, in microseconds, an order is active. Order is active as long as it is in NEW state.

Given an order file calculate the following distribution of holding period per ticker.
● Mean
● Median
● Max
● 75th percentile
● 90the percentile
● 99the percentile
● Standard deviation
```

Can someone please help me...Many Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Can you please post what you have got so far, in code? What exactly are you struggling with?

Answer (score 2):

Use pandas shift by functionality to have datetime of new state and current state in the same row

```
import pandas as pd

data = \
[{"DATETIME":"20171116 03:46:16.142514", 
"MODE":"ORD","INSTR":"INSTR1","TYPE":"New","id":1},
{"DATETIME":"20171116 03:46:16.243121"
,"MODE":"ORD","INSTR":"INSTR2","TYPE":"New","id":2},
{"DATETIME":"20171116 03:46:16.758292"
,"MODE":"ORD","INSTR":"INSTR3","TYPE":"New","id":3},
{"DATETIME":"20171116 03:46:17.212341"
,"MODE":"ORD","INSTR":"INSTR2","TYPE":"TRD","id":2},
{"DATETIME":"20171116 03:46:17.467893"
,"MODE":"ORD","INSTR":"INSTR1","TYPE":"CXL","id":1},
{"DATETIME":"20171116 03:46:18.924825"
,"MODE":"ORD","INSTR":"INSTR3","TYPE":"TRD","id":3}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.sort_values(by=['id','DATETIME'],inplace=True)

df['DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATETIME'])

# I am assuming that id 1's next state cannot be new again
df['DATETIME_shiftby_1'] = df['DATETIME'].shift(1)

df['hold_out_time'] = df['DATETIME'] - df['DATETIME_shiftby_1']

def fun(x):
    if(x.shape[0]>1):
#         returning the second term as shift by increses the index vale by 1. 
# So second row will contain datetime of new state as DATETIME_shiftby_1 and current datetime as DATETIME
        return x.iloc[1,6]
    else: return 'still active'

#This dataframe will contain the holdout time for every id

df.groupby(['id']).agg(fun)
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer, abhishek..But i get the following error : df2.groupby('id').agg(fun)



  File "C:\Users\owner\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 188, in _has_valid_tuple
    raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')

IndexingError: Too many indexers

Comment: Please copy and paste the above code and see if it's throwing any error. If not then copy and paste your code into a different question along with the full error log. It's very hard to debug a code with such shortened error messages.